# How to use ADOX to connect to existing Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007, adox

From a quick google i found out how to use ADOX to create a new database and add some tabels and rows to it. Here is an example:

```
using ADOX;
...
ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=mydb.accdb;");
Table mainTable = new Table();
mainTable.Name = "Test Table";
mainTable.Columns.Append("Column_1");
cat.Tables.Append(mainTable);
```

This creates a new database and works with that newly created database but **If I had an existing database, how would I get `ADOX.Catalog cat;` to connect to the existing database?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, i figured it out. You have to set the ActiveConenction property to an ADODB.connection object like in the following example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog

cnn.Open "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';" & _
    "Data Source= 'Northwind.mdb';"
Set cat.ActiveConnection = cnn
Debug.Print cat.Tables(0).Type

cnn.Close
Set cat = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cat.ActiveConnection` to set the connection string for an existing database, as illustrated by the following VBA code:

```
Sub adoxTest()
Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog, tbl As ADOX.Table
cat.ActiveConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
For Each tbl In cat.Tables
    Debug.Print tbl.Name
Next
Set tbl = Nothing
Set cat = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work but +1 for leading me into the right direction of setting the ActiveConnection property. Anyways i figured it out. have a look at my answer

Comment: @vidhu Thanks for the upvote. I guess C# is a bit more particular about the `.ActiveConnection` property than VBA is because I did test that code before I posted it and it did work for me.